# Why can't a string variable be overridden with a function variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I was trying to override a given javascript variable with a function, in case it is a string:

```
mapper = _.isString(mapper) ? function (item) { return item[mapper]; } : mapper;
```

But then, surprisingly, *mapper* was still the given string, and not the function!

Now when I assigned the same rvalue from the statement above to a new varialbe, it was behaving as expected:

```
var mapFunction = _.isString(mapper) ? function (item) { return item[mapper]; } : mapper;
```

(I was using *mapFunction* later in code, rather then *mapper*)

What was I missing? Can't I assign a function to a variable that used to be a string?

Comment: Can't reproduce this with `var mapper = 'e';`, then running your code.

Comment: That reference to 'mapper' inside of that function is not going to do what you think it will.

Comment: Guess epascarello is right, and since it's a scope issue, it actually won't reproduce that way. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob Did you forget this question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `mapper` inside the function is not going to remember the original value, it will be the new value when it is called.

So what you have is a reference to the function being used as the index.

You need to hold a copy and use that inside the function.

```
var _orgMapper = mapper;
mapper = _.isString(mapper) ? function (item) { return item[_orgMapper]; } : mapper;
```

Comment: That is true but doesn't seem to be related to the OP's question and doesn't explain how `mapper` could still be a string after the assignment. The fact that the variable was wrapped in a closure has no impact on the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Ternary operators aren't making mistakes ;)

```
var s = 's';

s = typeof s === 'string'? function () {} : s;

s; //function...
```

You just made the invalid assumption that `mapper` was a string or `_.isString` is buggy, which I doubt.

*Note: see @epascarello answer for another issue that you have which is related to closures.*